# acoustic length correction for expansion chamber/muffler query

Tags: acoustics

I am using the acoustic transfer matrix approach (equivalent to a two-port transmission line) for modelling acoustical systems, e.g. [see for more information](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Acoustics/Car_Mufflers):

This approach allows you to treat the system as a collection of sub-systems, which can then be successively matrix multiplied to give the total transfer matrix of the entire system, assuming only plane wave propagation in 1-dimension.

The simple system shown in the image below comprises of three sub-systems: an inlet duct, an expansion chamber, an outlet duct. One can apply acoustic length corrections to the lengths of the inlet and outlet ducts, $\delta$, as indicated by the dashed lines, which tries to account for the effect of the mass of air adjacent to the inlet and outlet ducts which is affected by its oscillations. This effectively reduces the length of the cavity from $a$ to $a_{eff}$, for the purpose of the transfer matrix for the expansion chamber element.

My question is, is it physically plausible for the acoustic correction lengths to become so large, such that $a_{eff} \to 0$? Essentially, it is as if the expansion chamber does not exist?

[image: example of expansion chamber with acoustic length corrections]

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that the whole subject of acoustic transmission lines and two-port models assumes that *the flow is approximately one-dimensional*.

If you have a very short "chamber", that is not the case. The idea of an "acoustic correction length" models the fact that there is *one* sudden change in cross section, but it doesn't take any account of *two* changes of cross section interacting with each other because they are close together.

In some situations it may be better to model the chamber as a resonant cavity that branches off side the main pipe, not as something in line with the pipe.

Comment: In response to your first point, would the two-port model still be valid, even for a short chamber, as long as the wavelength of the signal under consideration exceeds the length of the chamber (i.e. a lumped parameter approximation)?   Secondly, could you elaborate on why modelling the cavity as a resonator, rather than an inline element is sometimes better, and when this should be used? Do you have any references for this?